# How to find the number of objects with certain value for Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying get the number of objects where the status value is 'Served', so the value I should get is 2. I am not sure how to achieve this, what method should I ought to use.

```
{full_name: 'Jenny', phone_number: '8458 7098', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '14/11/1994', status: 'Served', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '1', gender: 'Female', race: 'Malay', height: '169', weight: '55'},
{full_name: 'Howard', phone_number: '8845 5888', email: '', dob: '09/11/1987', status: 'Served', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '2', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '175', weight: '75'},
{full_name: 'Kelly', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Current', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '3', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
{full_name: 'David Yang', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Next', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '4', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
{full_name: 'Jun Hao', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Next', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '5', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
{full_name: 'Xia Long', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Next', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '6', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
```

Comment: Those are not arrays. Those are objects. Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I did try using a loop but I don't think I have used right, because my code returns 2 2 instead a single 2.

Comment: Then post your code. I really can't even understand how a method could return 2 values.

Comment: `<div class="" *ngFor="let patient of patientlist"><div class="" *ngIf="patient.status === 'Served'"><a>{{patientlist.length}}</a></div></div>`
This my code, sorry my result is not 2 2 but 6 6

Comment: That displays the size of the whole array (`patientlist.length`) for every Served patient. What you need to write is a pure TypeScript function, which loops over the array, counts the elements with the 'Served' status, and returns the count.

Comment: How do I do that? sorry I am very inexperience at this

Comment: You don't know how to write a loop in TypeScript of JavaScript? Everyone has to start somewhere of course, but if that's true, you really shouldn't be using Angular yet. Practice with basic programming exercises. Here's some tutorial about the for loop: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_for_loop.htm

Comment: Oh I see thank you so much! I do not have much of a choice its sort of school thing and my teacher didn't go through in depth function for typescript, they try to focus more on Javascript since we primarily learn that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fast solution:

Put the data (objects) in an array:

```
private data = [
  {full_name: 'Jenny', phone_number: '8458 7098', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '14/11/1994', status: 'Served', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '1', gender: 'Female', race: 'Malay', height: '169', weight: '55'},
  {full_name: 'Howard', phone_number: '8845 5888', email: '', dob: '09/11/1987', status: 'Served', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '2', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '175', weight: '75'},
  {full_name: 'Kelly', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Current', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '3', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
  {full_name: 'David Yang', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Next', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '4', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
  {full_name: 'Jun Hao', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Next', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '5', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
  {full_name: 'Xia Long', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Next', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '6', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'}
];
```

write a small method to filter the entries. Here we filter the status:

```
getServedCount(): number {
  return this.data.filter(entry => entry.status === 'Served').length;
}
```

and in the template you just call the method to get the count:

```
COUNT: {{ getServedCount() }}
```

---

### Cleaner / Better solution:

Template:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

COUNT: {{ servedCount }}
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  // DATA can be provided via service, cookie, storage,... here we use so dummy data in a private variable.
  private data = [
    {full_name: 'Jenny', phone_number: '8458 7098', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '14/11/1994', status: 'Served', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '1', gender: 'Female', race: 'Malay', height: '169', weight: '55'},
    {full_name: 'Howard', phone_number: '8845 5888', email: '', dob: '09/11/1987', status: 'Served', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '2', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '175', weight: '75'},
    {full_name: 'Kelly', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Current', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '3', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
    {full_name: 'David Yang', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Next', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '4', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
    {full_name: 'Jun Hao', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Next', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '5', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'},
    {full_name: 'Xia Long', phone_number: '9145 5843', email: 'Example@yahoo.com', dob: '25/02/1960', status: 'Next', appointment_type: 'Online', queue_num: '6', gender: 'Male', race: 'Chinese', height: '172', weight: '63'}
  ];

  // variable to access from the template
  public servedCount = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // triggers the "getServedCount" method only once.
    this.servedCount = this.getServedCount(this.data);
  }

  private getServedCount(data): number {
    return data.filter(entry => entry.status === 'Served').length;
  }
}
```

And here the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-filter-in-angular-component) :-)

Comment: You are welcome :-)

(I don't know why people downvote a correct answer. Without comments. Strange.)

Comment: @brandt.codes Not sure why the downvote, but it's a very bad practice to call a function like you did in your template sample.

Comment: @developer033 Thanks! Sure, this method get called every time the change detection is triggered. I would prefer a pure pipe to avoid performance issues. But the answer would be more complex and I'm not sure if it is helpful for a beginner.

Comment: @developer033 Thanks for informing me, how should I call the function as good practice?

Comment: @brandt.codes Well, what you can do is to answer "completely": with the **bad** way for simplicity, and with the right/good way :) I'd love people teaching me the right way when I was starting.

Comment: @LimHanYang It depends on the context... you can just assign the result you want in a variable or create a pipe and use it in template.

Comment: ok, you're right @developer033. I adjusted my answer. Feel free to extend :-)

Comment: @developer033@brandt.codes Than yous for teaching me you guys have been a great help to me.